# angular 1.5 (components) - how to use jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an experience with "old-style" angular, where i was using directive. And if i wanna use some jQuery plugin, like `niceScroll`... And in old angular i created directive, with such directive-body:

```
element.niceScroll()
```

and then on element in html i added attr: `some-directive`

now i'm trying to do it with angular 1.5. But i stopped with one problem:

how can i use it with components? what should i write in controller, what in component, what in .js ?
maybe anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives are still there and you should still use them to wrap jquery plugins in most cases.

Most of such directives will:

- Have not isolated scope.
- Have no template
- restrict to AC (attribute/class)

(Most of standard directives follow this conditions)

For rest you can create components.

Comment: and what about scope in directive?

Comment: Petr what would you do if the jQuery plugin returned something that you need to use in the parent component?  Eg a component [here](https://github.com/lpsBetty/angular-croppie/blob/master/angular-croppie.js) is nice because the isolated scope makes passing the output easier and more modular, and yet it violates your stated principles.

Comment: I did not say components are bad. Just that if you can not do something with 1.5 component in comfortable way - do not afraid of writing a directive cause it absolutely normal for certain things.